# GNU sed to BSD sed for bash goto function

Tags: bash, sed, bsd

I make extensive use of a bash goto function that works through a GNU sed command. However, the sed command is not compatible with BSD sed. How would I need to change it to function correctly in an operating system that uses BSD sed, such as MacOS?

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptDir="$(cd "$( dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" && pwd)"

function goto
{
    shortcutName=$1
    newPosition=$(sed -n -e "/: $shortcutName$/{:a;n;p;ba};" "$scriptDir/$(basename -- "$BASH_SOURCE")" )
    eval "$newPosition"
    exit
}
alias :="goto"

# script code

: somegotolabel

# script code

goto somegotolabel
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally, I'd rewrite that sed in awk if you want it to be portable. But then, I'd also call trying to use `eval` to extract a subset of a source file and execute it with eval on the pretense that that constitutes a "goto" horrifying. (A proper goto doesn't create a stack frame! A proper goto can jump from one place inside a function to a different place inside that same function! And a proper language feature doesn't make assumptions that allow it to be used only from a single source file, no matter how many files your project contains)

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by using `goto`s instead of calling functions? Unless you're trying to win an obfuscated (and fragile) code contest, don't do this. Simply define and call functions and/or use other clear, simple language constructs to control the execution flow of your code instead of trying to execute ad-hoc chunks of code as if they existed at goto labels. Also, `:` already has a meaning and it's not `goto`, it's `true`, don't redefine it.

Comment: In bsd-ish sed, labels extend to end of line, not until semicolon. so use newlines instead of semicolons.

Comment: But since your goto labels cannot appear on line 1 (the shebang line), you could just use `sed "1,/: $shortcutName$/d" ...`

Comment: On MacOS, I simply installed (using homebrew) GNU sed and hence I have both at my disposal.

Comment: user1934428 - That is definitely a good solution for this situation.
jhnc - Very helpful. Thanks!

Ed / Charles - This is a unique situation involving the mass conversion of thousands of Windows batch files to bash. I realize doing things this way is very disturbing and feels incredibly wrong, but it is necessary. Using $BASH_SOURCE to set scriptDir allows the goto function to keep working when other shell scripts are called as long as the scriptDir variable is reset upon returning to the parent script.